# Two view controllers use same table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm new to iOS development. I want to know how to pass back data from same tableview to two different view controller.

This is my didselectrow method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
sendarea = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Step2ClassifiedViewController *parentViewC = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 2];
parentViewC.areareceive = sendarea;
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];


 }
```

But this is only for one view. I have another view also need to pass back the data if i use the same table. Is that possible? or do i just need to create another table?.

Comment: no need , you tableview contains different data or Static Data for navigation selction, else show some sample output on tableview

Comment: You are not following MVC. The  Tableview is 'V', your data should be in 'M'.

Comment: Passing data to any number of controllers is possible. However, your question is not very specific. When you pass back data to your other view controller as well, what do you want to do? You can jump back to only one view controller. It can be any view controller you want but has to be one particular view controller. So, please specify, what you want to do when you pass data to that other View Controller.

Comment: @natasha my table contain list of state. When user select the state then it pop back to previous view and show the selected state. That's why I want to pass data.

Comment: @trojanfoe sorry i don't get what u mean. Can u explain more since i'm still in learning process.

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH32-SW1).

Comment: If that is the case then, you have to check the state in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and based on the state you can load the desired View Controller and pass data along with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same table. Only you need change the data source. And can call in each **didSelectRowAtIndexpath**

*This is just like, A taxi driver carries passenger by his one taxi. When his taxi is empty,he can carries passenger.*

Comment: means in didSelectRowAtIndexpath can call many view controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    sendarea = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if(state == 1){
        Step2ClassifiedViewController *parentViewC = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 2];
        parentViewC.areareceive = sendarea;
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else if (state == 2){
        //get your other View Controller and set data before pop to that view controller.
        NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
        for(UIViewController *vc in viewControllers){
            if([vc isKindOfClass:[OtherViewController class]]){
                OtherViewController *otherVC = (OtherViewController*)vc;
                otherVC.areareceive = sendarea;
                [[self navigationController] popToViewController:otherVC animated:YES];
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        //load any View Controller you want
    }
}
```

Based on your question and the comments, I assume that you want to load different View Controllers based on your different state and pass along data.

The above is one way of doing that. However, you could also use delegation for your purpose, it would be a good programming practise.